# Java 2D: Why won't my JPanel let me resize it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

Ok so I am trying to add a JPanel to a JFrame as so:

```
            gameClasses[2] = new a2();
            gameClasses[2].setSize(100, 100);
            menu.add(gameClasses[2]);
            menu.setVisible(true);
```

a2() is a separate class that acts as a JPanel which I use the paintComponent to paint images to it.  "menu" is the JFrame.  My problem is when I call "gameClasses[2].setSize(100, 100);" it does not resize the JPanel but it stays the same size.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how this is supposed to be done because no one else seems to have any issues with this on the internet.  Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the code related to menu and a2:

```
            menu.setSize(swidth / 2 + swidth / 5, sheight / 2 + sheight / 5);
            menu.setLocation((swidth - menu.getWidth()) / 2, (sheight -     menu.getHeight()) / 3);
            menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            menu.setResizable(true);
            menu.remove(main);
            menu.add(gameClasses[0] = new a3());
            menu.add(gameClasses[1] = new a4());
            gameClasses[2] = new a2();
            gameClasses[2].setSize(100, 100);
            gameClasses[2].validate();
            menu.add(gameClasses[2]);
            menu.setVisible(true);

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class a2 extends JPanel {

public static int size = 48;
public static Image grsX = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tiles/grsX.png");
public static Image grsY = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tiles/grsY.png");
public static Image grsX1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tiles/grsX1.png");
public static Image grsY1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tiles/grsY1.png");

public a2() {
    System.out.println("a2 loaded...");
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //draw interface
    for(int y = 0; y < a6.ay; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < a6.ax; x++) {
            g.drawImage(a5.Tile_Img.get(a5.ID_Tile.get(a6.area[x][y])), x * size, y * size, size, size, this);
            if(x > 0) {
                if(a6.area[x - 1][y].equals("00") && a6.area[x][y].equals("01")) {
                    g.drawImage(grsX, x * size, y * size, size, size, this);
                }
            }
            if(x < a6.ax - 1) {
                if(a6.area[x + 1][y].equals("00") && a6.area[x][y].equals("01")) {
                    g.drawImage(grsX1, x * size, y * size, size, size, this);
                }
            }
            if(y > 0) {
                if(a6.area[x][y - 1].equals("00") && a6.area[x][y].equals("01")) {
                    g.drawImage(grsY, x * size, y * size, size, size, this);
                }
            }
            if(y < a6.ay - 1) {
                if(a6.area[x][y + 1].equals("00") && a6.area[x][y].equals("01")) {
                    g.drawImage(grsY1, x * size, y * size, size, size, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

}

a3 and a4 are a KeyListener class and a MouseListener class that both extend JPanel

Comment: It's impossible to know where you're going wrong unless you post all relevant code. Or better yet, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is `gameClasses` a panel and `menu` a (very poorly named) frame?  That's what I'd guess, but since I don't like guessing, I'll 2nd Jeffrey's suggestion to post an SSCCE.

Comment: That is all the relevant code except that a2 extends JPanel and works and the only things I changed about menu were to setLayout(null) and setResizable(true)

Comment: *"all the relevant code"*  If you knew what the relevant code was, you would be 98% of the way to fixing this.  As it happens, the `setLayout(null)` is central to the problem.  ***Don't do that!***

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler In this case, anywhere you use `menu` and the code for `a2` would be relevant. However, your problem is almost certainly with the `null LayoutManager`.

Comment: I am no longer setting the layout to null yet it still does not work. I will post all code I have relating to menu and a2.

Comment: BTW - last comment before you post an SSCCE.  Calling `repaint()` from within `paintComponent()` causes an infinite loop until the point that the JRE decides to *ignore* a call to repaint.

Comment: I know that I just had it there until I implemented my KeyListener to move things around. I just started a new mini project but I cannot resize this JPanel.  It resizes when you do not paint onto it but not when you do

Comment: Ok I set the answer as accepted thanks and srry I am pretty new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A layout is more likely to respect the preferred size than the size.
- A call to `pack()` on the frame will make it become the minimum size needed to display the components inside.  Call it after everything is added.
- Don't call `setLayout(null)` (mentioned in comment as 'non-relevant' code).  ***Use layouts.***

Comment: Thanks it somewhat works but when I call pack() on menu, it changes the menu to 100 * 100 but not the JPanel... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Wait.. nevermind pack() makes the JFrame small but not the size I set to the JPanel

Comment: *"Any other suggestions?"*  ***Post an S-S-C-C-E.*** (As opposed to the mostly useless code snippets and dribs'n'drabs of information.)

Comment: Anything I have posted and edited above is just as good as an SSCCE and is right there for everyone to read.

Comment: *"Anything I have posted and edited above is just as good as an SSCCE"*  It is not good enough to get further help from me.  Best of luck with it.

Comment: @MrDrProfessorTyler What you posted is not self-contained nor compileable. It is no where near as good as an SSCCE.